# verification if record posts to multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, c#

i hope i have another simple question for someone out there.
im currently working on a website where i am having a user post information to the server and upon posting they are taken to a verification page that tells them if it successfully was stored on the .mbd table or not. I have had no problems with doing this for a single table but i seem to be running into a issue when wanting to verifing the information stored on multiple tables.

HERE is the code that im using THAT IS WORKING for posting to a  SINGLE table

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtVerifiedInfo.Text =   Session["txtUserFirstName"].ToString() +
    "\n" + Session["txtUserLastName"].ToString() +
    "\n" + Session["txtUserName"].ToString() +
    "\n" + Session["txtUserPassword"].ToString() +
```

;

```
    // Check if the record is successfully saved in the tblUserLogin Table and prints the appropriate message in the text box txtVerifiedInfo
    if (clsDataLayer.SavePersonnel(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\WSC_DB.mdb"),
    Session["txtUserFirstName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtUserLastName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtUserName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtUserPassword"].ToString(),

                                         ))
    {
        txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
        "\nThe information was successfully saved!";

    }
    else
    {
        txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
        "\nThe information was NOT saved.";
    }
}
```

}

Here is what i have attempted with not much luck at all

```
if (clsDataLayer.Saveneworder(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\WSC_DB.mdb"),
    Session["txtfirstName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtlastName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtstreetAddress"].ToString(),
    Session["txtcity"].ToString(),
    Session["txtzipCode"].ToString()))


    && if (clsDataLayer.Savenewitem(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\WSC_DB.mdb"),

    Session["jobType"].ToString() +
    Session["txtmediaContent"].ToString()))

    {
        txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
        "\nThe Order successfully submitted!";

    }
    else
    {
        txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
        "\n The order did not save, please return to the previous screen and verify all of yourr data is correct, thank you.";
    }
}
```

}

I Imagine im not that close to doing this correctly but hopefully in the ball park.

any help with this would be great. 
Thank you for your time

Comment: The expression `if (condition) && if (condition2)` does not make sense. It should be `if (condition && condition2)`. I'm not 100% sure that's the only problem though..

Comment: Thanks - i will try moving that around. yea the part that doesnt make sense to me if having the different sessions for each table and trying to list them all under the same if statement.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, this is roughly what you have now:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("App_Data\\WSC_DB.mdb");
if (clsDataLayer.Saveorder(path, [order parameters] 
    && clsDataLayer.Saveitem(path, [item parameters])
{
  txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
    "\nThe Order successfully submitted!";
}
else
{
  txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
    "\n The order did not save, please return to the previous screen and verify all of yourr data is correct, thank you.";
}
```

The code you've presented is not well structured, in that there is an unnecessary call to `Server.MapPath` and the call may be better placed as part of an argument to the constructor of your datalayer class.

What you may not be aware of is the `&&` is a shortcut operator - the second part of the argument will not be called if the first part fails. Is this the behaviour you want?

I suspect you want `Saveorder` AND `Saveitem` to succeed or fail together, as part of one transaction. That being the case, you might be better off writing a new method in your datalayer class that does exactly that.

I'm assuming the `.mdb` in your filename indicates you're using MS Access? I'm not sure if it deals with transactions as well as SQL server (for instance), so you might need to write your own code to remove the order if its item cannot be saved (or whatever on-failure behaviour you need).